# Write downloadable extensions for mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ionic-framework, add-on

**Short:**
Is it possible to write a mobile application where you can download some kind of extensions/add-ons (like in desktop programs) that are not previously shipped in the app archive?

**Long:**
I am developing a mobile app with a shared base functionality but different modules for different clients. As the app is growing rapidly and the modules are quite different, it would make sense, not to pack every module into the apk from the beginning but to ship only the base code to all clients and they can select and download the modules they would like to use. Regarding apk size and speed this would offer definately advantages. Splitting the app into several smaller apps with different package names on the other hand would be very hard to maintain. Currently I'm using Ionic but the question would be equally interesting for native apps.
Searching the web returned nothing of value, so I'm wondering whether there is a way to acchieve this...

Comment: "Splitting the app into several smaller apps with different package names on the other hand would be very hard to maintain" -- compared to implementing and securing a plugin system?

Comment: This is not permitted on iOS by [App Store guideline 2.5.2](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements). Doing this would lead to rejection by Apple

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm not sure if you can have a class loader as you have in Java for doing such things. But the res folder probably will not work.

Another approach is to launch every plugin as a different application, and design those activities to work with startForResult so you can communicate and open all other apps while looking like you are within the same application.